# Getting only file name as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, file-upload

i am trying to upload a file in rails

i have created a model with following code

```
def self.save(upload,id)
    name =  upload[:img].original_filename
    directory = "public/user_db"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, id)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['img'].read) }
  end
end
```

my view have following field.

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="file" name="img" id="img" placeholder="upload your DP" />
</div>
```

my controller is calling save function as following
:

```
post = DataFile.save(params,@fbuser.id)
```

But a am getting this error[image]

Comment: Quick note, you've overridden the save method on your model, so when you've cleared this error, you'll probably find that it is not saved to the database. You can call the standard save method inside your custom save method by calling `super` inside it.

Comment: i am not saving in db i am trying to save in a folder. bu this code is treating file as a string.

Comment: Fair enough, if you're not saving any other attributes.

Comment: he is NOT overiding the sae. its self.safe so its non activerecord related class stuff

Answer (score 3):

do yourself a favor and don't reinvent the wheel. In Rails there are 3 awesome gems to handle file-uploading with eatch having a great community for support and tons of shared code.

**Carrierwave**
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

**Paperclip** 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

**Dragonfly**
https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly

Just follow the instructions for Installation, migrate the database, tell your models how to behave and you lost all the headache within 5 minutes :-)

**regarding your problem-**

`name =  upload[:img].original_filename` this throws an expection because `upload[:img]` ist just containing a string. So there is no need for the `.original_filename`

but again - please use one of those gems (or maybe just read the code to get an idea of how to do). There are also Railscasts out there
http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads
and http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp_kn6afl-Y

cheers

Comment: thanks for you good suggestion but i have assigned this task to complete without gems so can you please provide me help regarding this problem

Comment: if you really want to do this by your own - please read the sourcecode of a gem and see how they are doing.

actually you are kinda on a rough way with using variables like params[:img] and own custom stuff. pretty sure there are plenty of tutorials out, how to do this. without sharing your code, we cant help you

Answer (score 1):

A have just the tag in view and very thing start working :) thanks for your help. the line is following

```
<%= f.file_field "img" %>
```

and in controller

```
post = DataFile.save(params[:fbuser],@fbuser.id.to_s)
```